# component.namingContainer.parent skips h:form

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, composite-component, naming-containers

I made a composite component, inside it is an <f:ajax> tag, and its "render" attribute is a parameter of the cc.

something like this:

```
    ...
    <cc:attribute name="additionalAjaxRenderIds" type="java.lang.String"></cc:attribute>
    ...
    <h:commandLink value="test" action="#{myBean.someAction}" id="testLink" >
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="#{cc.attrs.additionalAjaxRenderIds} "/>
    </h:commandLink>
    ...
```

I use this cc inside a form, thats already in an outer naming container:

```
    <h:form id="myForm">
        ...
        <mycomp:myComponent id="myCC" additionalAjaxRenderIds=":#{component.namingContainer.parent.clientId}:myPanel" />
        <h:panelGroup id="myPanel">
            ...
        </h:panelGroup>
        ...
    </h:form>
```

The problem is, if i write

```
additionalAjaxRenderIds=":#{component.namingContainer.clientId}:myPanel"
```

i get this error:

```
<f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':j_idt44:myForm:myCC:myPanel' - cannot locate it in the context of the component testLink
```

while if i use this (+ .parent):

```
additionalAjaxRenderIds=":#{component.namingContainer.parent.clientId}:myPanel"
```

the error is:

```
<f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':j_idt44:myPanel' - cannot locate it in the context of the component testLink
```

instead of the expected id:

```
':j_idt44:myForm:myPanel'
```

so it seems like the parent of my cc's naming container is not the form, but the outer namingcontainer

Is there any way to:
1, get the right parent (the form)
2, evaluate the EL before i pass it as a parameter (so i can pass the calculated clientId to my cc instead of the EL expression, so the component wont refer to the commandLink tag, but to the h:form in which i put my cc)

I know i could use

```
additionalAjaxRenderIds=":#{component.namingContainer.parent.clientId}:myForm:myPanel"
```

but i dont like that solution

Also, setting the form's prependId attribute to false breaks the whole component lookup (and the ajax tag too as a result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL expressions are not evaluated at the moment the component is built, but at the moment the attribute is accessed. In other words, they're *runtime* and not *buildtime*. The `#{component}` refers to the *current* UI component at the moment the EL expression is evaluated, which is in your particular case the `<h:commandLink>`. That explains the different outcome.

You need to approach this differently, without using `#{component}`.

E.g.

```
<h:form id="myForm" binding="#{myForm}">
    ...
    <mycomp:myComponent id="myCC" additionalAjaxRenderIds=":#{myForm.clientId}:myPanel" />
    <h:panelGroup id="myPanel">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
    ...
</h:form>
```

or

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    ...
    <mycomp:myComponent id="myCC" additionalAjaxRenderIds=":#{myPanel.clientId}" />
    <h:panelGroup id="myPanel" binding="#{myPanel}">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
    ...
</h:form>
```

Comment: _The #{component} refers to the current UI component at the moment the EL expression is evaluated, which is in your particular case the <h:commandLink>_ - i know that, my problem there is that when i use #{component.namingContainer **.parent** } instead of #{component.namingContainer}, it seems like it jumps up two levels in the hierarchy, instead of 1 (the parent of that namingcontainer, which in this case is myCC, should be the myForm in my understanding) - apart from that your sollution works, so i will mark it as correct answer later (still waiting for an explanation why this happens)